# Parsing text into dimensional hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to convert this string of text into a hash for creating pages based on users input.

```
Home
About
- News
-- Local News
-- Global News
- Who We Are
Product
```

This is just an example, but I'd like to convert this into a multidimensional hash I can iterate through. I want to create an easy way for users to create pages in a CMS.

I've played around with splitting up the string and regular expressions, but I haven't made it far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show some code you've tried.

Comment: what is a multidimentional hash?

Comment: @sawa it's a Hash that has other hashes as its values.  Nested hash is another term for it.  You can see examples in the answers below (the output of the methods)

Comment: @ScottHelm I know nested hashes, but I don't think it can be called multidimensional hash.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Yaml would be your friend.  Look at Yaml.load.
test.yml:

```
"Home":
  "About":
    "News":
      "Local News":
      "Global News":
      "Who We Are":
  "Products":
```

irb

```
require 'yaml'
YAML.load(File.open('test.yml'))
=> {"home"=>{"About"=>{"News"=>{"Local News"=>nil, "Global News"=>nil, "Who We Are"=>nil}}, "Product"=>nil}}
```

Comment: Just want to add: If you want to do a parser on your own, have a look at [Parslet](http://kschiess.github.com/parslet/)

Comment: As [Rails has just found out](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2013/01/10/rails-remote-code-execution-vulnerability-explained/), you want to be very careful if you're going to `YAML.load` anything user-editable!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt. I fully acknowledge that it doesn't look idiomatic and there might be a one-liner in ruby stdlib that can replace this. But hey, at least this works :)

So, the basic idea is this:

- break text to separate lines
- iterate this line array and gradually build the hash. Keep tracking "current node" while you do this
- if this line has more '-' characters then previous one, then this line must be child of the previous
- and so on

Code:

```
txt = <<-TXT
Home
About
- News
-- Local News
-- Global News
- Who We Are
Product
TXT

def lines_to_hash lines
  res = {}
  last_level = 0
  parent_stack = [res]
  last_line = nil

  lines.each do |line|
    cur_level = line.scan('-').length
    if cur_level > last_level
      parent_stack << parent_stack.last[last_line]
    elsif cur_level < last_level
      parent_stack.pop
    end

    clean_line = line.gsub(/^[-\s]+/, '')
    parent_stack.last[clean_line] = {}
    last_line = clean_line
    last_level = cur_level
  end
  res
end

res = lines_to_hash(txt.split("\n"))
res # => {"Home"=>{}, 
    #     "About"=>{"News"=>{"Local News"=>{}, "Global News"=>{}}, 
    #               "Who We Are"=>{}}, 
    #     "Product"=>{}}
```

If someone comes up with a one-liner, I'll award +100 rep in bounty :)

Comment: [Challenge accepted!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280573/parsing-text-into-dimensional-hash/14282912#14282912)

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = <<-TXT
Home
About
- News
-- Local News
-- Global News
- Who We Are
Product
TXT

def hashify s
  Hash[s.split(/^(?!-)\s*(.*)/).drop(1).each_slice(2).map{|k, v| [k, hashify(v.to_s.strip.gsub(/^-/, ""))]}]
end

hashify(txt)
# =>
# {
#   "Home"    => {},
#   "About"   => {
#     "News"       => {
#       "Local News"  => {},
#       "Global News" => {}
#     },
#     "Who We Are" => {}
#   },
#   "Product" => {}
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sergio: Here's a one-liner! (Admittedly I have split it onto several lines for "clarity")

@lt-matt8: If you actually use this then I take no responsibility for the sanity of anyone coming to read your code later :)

```
text = <<-TEXT
Home
About
- News
-- Local News
-- Global News
- Who We Are
Product
TEXT

hash = text.lines.each_with_object([{}]) {|item, levels|
  item.match(/(-*)\s*(.*)/).captures.tap {|level, title|
    levels[level.size][title] = (levels[level.size + 1] = {})
  }
}.first
# => {"Home"=>{}, "About"=>{"News"=>{"Local News"=>{}, "Global News"=>{}}, "Who We Are"=>{}}, "Product"=>{}}
```

Comment: While your answer technically qualifies, @sawa's answer is shorter. And his post is older.

Comment: Anyway, I'll have to wait 2 days to start the bounty.

Comment: Oh agreed, @sawa's is much better. I was just trying to do it without recursion - if you have to define a method is it still technically a one-liner? ;)

Comment: Ah, recursion! Well, I guess, technically it's not a one-liner. Then your version wins :)

Comment: You guys are right. Mine has recursion, and is not a one liner in the strict sense. No objection against Sergio awarding Andy.